# Print two elements from array with for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new in JavaScript and i am trying to print only two elements from array with FOR LOOP and brake & continue statements

**for example i want to be printed 3 and 8**

I tried this:

```
var array= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (i == 3) {
        alert(i);
        continue;
    }       

    if ( i == 8) {
        alert(i);       
    }
}
```

Comment: `array.length` is `8`, but the loop only runs when `i < 8`.

Comment: You're not printing elements from the array, you're printing indexes. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All arrays start at the first position of `0` and go up from there. So in your code you are thinking you are comparing `3 == 3` in but really you are comparing `2 == 3`. If you compare the array position value instead of the loop value your problem is fixed.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == 3) { 
        alert(array[i]);
    }
    else if (array[i] == 8) { 
        alert(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what i wanted 

thank you for the position explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if you need to check for values in array and not index. Imo, values in array need not be similar as index values,they can be anything.

```
var array= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

 for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{ 

   if (array[i]== 3 || array[i] == 8)
   { 
        alert(array[i]);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a `filter`?

```
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
const matches = array.filter(a => a === 3 || a === 8);
console.log(matches[0], matches[1]);

// The filter uses the lambda function. It's the same thing as the following:
const matches = array.filter(function(a) {
    return a === 3 || a === 8;
});
```